# Landsat 8 striping/banding citation

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, google-earth-engine, landsat-8

**Does anyone have or know a citation for the Landsat 8 striping that affects some scenes (Brazil shown here).**  It's apparent in all bands (B3 here at 100% stretch) and is present in both RAW and Surface Reflectance imagery.  It's impacting an image classification's accuracy and I can't seem to find much info about it in the [Known Issues](https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-8-data-users-handbook-appendix-a) from USGS.  I've found [this document](https://surfaceheat.sites.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Striping.pdf) from a [Yale website](https://surfaceheat.sites.yale.edu/understanding-landsat-8), but again, can't seem to find a primary source to cite.

[Google Earth Engine link to script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f05f2f6f5342673287810681f3e31cb1) showing the striping effect at Band 3. The script also allows the export of a subset of the product `LC08_L1TP_230066_20170621_20170630_01_T1`

[image]

Comment: Did you download it from the USGS Earth Explorer or from the Google Earth Engine ??

Comment: Google Earth Engine.  I provided the link to reproduce it at the bottom.

Comment: Can you go back to the USGS Earth Explorer and there should be information there if you see the same scene ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  It's 100% in the image and not an artifact of the provider.  The image quality is 9 for both OLI and TIRS

Comment: Are you seeking more information about this image ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this is OLI data? This is the type of artifact, after correction, that is observed in ETM+7 due to the scan-alignment error. I have never seen this in OLI. I would recommend downloading the same image from earth explorer to see if the artifacts are actually associated with the image or if it is a result of post-processing in GEE. I would imagine that it is possible that this type of banding could result from nearest neighbor sampling during reprojection.

Comment: I second @JeffreyEvans comments--I have not heard of striping issues with OLI either. The link you provide does not show any imagery only a gray bounding box. Have you tried visualizing the imagery in Erdas, Envi, ArcGIS, or QGIS? I am wondering if the image is rendering improperly on GEE, but would render fine using a GIS or image processing software.

Comment: @Aaron in order to tune the visualizations in GEE you'll need to adjust the bands and stretch- didn't know how to code that in myself

Comment: @JeffreyEvans  it's definitely OLI and it's definitely present.  Here's a screen grab from the Earth Explorer download of B3. 
 Note the banding is fainter in this scene. https://imgur.com/YJrKs3g.

Comment: The striping is apparent in Band 3 of `LC08_L1TP_230066_20170621_20170630_01_T1`. The striping is visible in EarthEngine as well as in an exported subset - see [the extended script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8fed8b9756abc4ebe11af6f223cfdaf6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Morfitt et al. 2015 (Remote Sensing)](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/7/2/2208/htm) provides a description of the effect and its cause. See Figure 1 for Focal Plane Module (FPM) layout and Section 3.2.2 for causes of discontinuities across FPM boundaries (and Figures 8-10 for examples).  The effect is "generally uncorrectable."

Answer (score 2):

Looks more like different OLI sensor segments. This usually can be seen over water, but like in this case sometimes it persists on images taken over land.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. It seems to be the most correct answer here. Here is a reference: https://landsat.usgs.gov/why-am-i-seeing-slight-vertical-striping-some-landsat-8-operational-land-imager-oli-images

Answer (score 2):

This is so called ["Memory effect"](https://landsat.usgs.gov/why-are-there-light-and-dark-lines-across-my-landsat-image) and it has been around since the sensor is in orbit. It is quite common for optical space-borne sensors, you can see similar effect in Sentinel-2 MSI and Sentinel-3 OLCI sensors.

Comment: I do not think this is memory effect, which would manifest as dark and white stripes perpendicular to the direction of satellite travel.